# How to find matching percentage between columns value Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find out matching percentage between the columns, Based on the unique column values trying to find the matching accuracy percentage with respect to other specific columns.

How could it be done? Or this is not common practice in python? But what i found in most cases to perform the matching by using fuzzy match.

```
Sheet 1

identity_no  address            Pincode   company_name

 IN2231      Delhi, Indi        110030    AXN pvt Ltd
 UK654       London, Uk         897653    Aviva Intl Ltd
 SL1432      Colombo, Srilanka  07658     Ship Incorporations
 LK0678      Libya, Sns         5674332   Oppo Mobiles pvt ltd
```

**Sheet 2**

```
identity_no  address            Pincode   company_name

 IN2231      Delhi, India       110030    AXN pvt Ltd
 UK654       London, Uk         897653    Aviva Intl Ltd
 SL1432      Colombo, Srilanka  07658     Ship Incorporations
```

**Expected Output:**

```
identity_no  address            Pincode   company_name               match_percent
    
     IN2231      Delhi, Indi        110030    AXN pvt Ltd                
     UK654       London, Uk         897653    Aviva Intl Ltd
     SL1432      Colombo, Srilanka  07658     Ship Incorporations
     LK0678      Libya, Sns         5674332   Oppo Mobiles pvt ltd
```

Here having two different excel sheets where sheet1 is the input data whereas sheet 2 is the master dataset, we have to match ['address', 'Pincode', 'company_name'] from **sheet1 with sheet2** and find the match percentage by using identity_no.

```
df = pd.read_excel(open(r'input.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(open(r'master_data.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet2')

from difflib import SequenceMatcher
lst = df2[['identity_no','address', 'Pincode', 'company_name']]

def closest(s):
    highest = 0
    result = ''
    for i in lst:
        temp = SequenceMatcher(None, s, i).ratio() #Similarity Ratio
        if temp > highest:
            highest = temp
            result = i
    return result
```

I am not getting the right way to find the match percentage and submit the values in "match_percent" column.

Comment: I would take a look at the fuzzymatcher package.

Comment: What do you mean by match percent? Can you fill in the numbers expected for this input?

Comment: @SKPS - I need the accuracy percentage by matching the ['address', 'Pincode', 'company_name'] columns from sheet1 with sheet2, i.e percentage of accuracy between both the dataframes. how accurate the the value between both the sheets.

Comment: @EricTruett  - For Eg. from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz , 
value = fuzz.ratio('New York', 'New York')
print('value: ' + str(value))